# React Native WebView: Microphone Issue on iOS in Background (Expo SDK 49)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, webrtc

I’m encountering a problem with my React Native app (Expo SDK 49) when initiating a call through a WebView. When the app is active, the microphone works fine, and the other user can hear my voice. However, when the app is in the background on iOS devices, the microphone is not picking up my voice.

This issue is specific to iOS; Android works as expected. Any insights or solutions on how to enable the microphone in the background on iOS devices within a React Native WebView would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the steps I tried:

```
1.  I attempted to address the issue by adding permission as a task in the background, but I’m uncertain if I implemented it correctly.
```

This problem seems isolated to iOS; Android behaves as expected. Any insights or solutions regarding enabling the microphone in the background on iOS devices within a React Native WebView would be highly valuable.

Thanks in advance!